# Delegate method called twice in Xcode 8.1/Swift 3.0 with debugger breakpoint

Tags: xcode, delegates, swift3, overriding

I have a problem with xcode 8.1/swift 3.  I think it might be a bug in the debugger XCode software but thought I would see if anybody sees something I am missing.  I am working on an ios application where I need to override the backspace method used with UITextField. I setup a delegate to watch for the backspace key being pressed.  The program works until I set a debugger breakpoint in the overridden method (see code below).  When I do this the backspace method gets called twice for each time I press the key instead of just one time. If I delete breakpoint the code works. Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong?  Here is the code thanks for your help!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, EqFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let newField = EqField()
    newField.myDelegate = self
    newField.becomeFirstResponder()
    view.addSubview(newField)
    newField.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 150)

}

func backspacePressed( ){

    print("in backspacePressed") // breakpoint added here
}

}
```

Here is the subclass of UITextField:

```
import UIKit

class EqField: UITextField {

    var myDelegate: EqFieldDelegate?

    override func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()
        myDelegate?.backspacePressed()
    }
}

protocol EqFieldDelegate {
    func backspacePressed()
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's calling twice?  When hits the breakpoint and you hit continue it hits it again?  Or what specifically?

Comment: I made a test project with the provided code and can verify - not only does the breakpoint get hit twice, the log prints twice as well. Without the breakpoint, the log prints once.

Comment: It sometimes happens with XCode debugger. Debugger sometimes misbehaved when working with UI elements and their delegates.

Comment: As already noted the code is getting called twice.  In the actual program I am working on two things get deleted instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory about why this is happening.

To illustrate, imagine we're making our own back button. It should have the following behavior to mimic Apple's:

1. On touch down, call `backspacePressed`
2. After .5 seconds, if touch is still down, call `backspacePressed` again
3. After every .1 seconds, if touch is still down, call `backspacePressed` again

Here's how I would implement it:

1. Add this to the end of your `viewDidLoad`

   ```
   let button = UIButton(type: .system)
   button.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleButtonTouched(button:)), for: .touchDown)
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleButtonReleased(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: newField.frame.maxY, width: 200, height: 150)
   view.addSubview(button)
   ```
2. Add this after `viewDidLoad`

   ```
   var buttonTimer: Timer?

   func handleButtonTouched(button: UIButton) {
       buttonTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false, block: { [weak self] timer in

           print("button's been held down for a while!")
           self?.backspacePressed()

           self?.buttonTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
               print("button's still held down")
               self?.backspacePressed()
           })

       })
       print("button was pressed") // add a breakpoint here
       self.backspacePressed()
   }


   func handleButtonReleased(button: UIButton) {
       buttonTimer?.invalidate()
   }
   ```
3. (Optional) Comment out your log so your console matches mine for this experiment

   ```
   func backspacePressed( ){
       //print("in backspacePressed")
   }
   ```

Without a breakpoint, if you tap and hold this button, you'll get logs printed following the behavior I outlined above:

```
button was pressed
button's been held down for a while!
button's still held down
button's still held down
button's still held down
button's still held down
```

If you just tap the button (don't hold it), you'll just get

```
button was pressed
```

However, if you set the breakpoint, tap the button, and wait for a second after the breakpoint hits before pressing continue, you get two logs:

```
button was pressed
button's been held down for a while!
```

You'd think, since you didn't hold the button for long enough, you wouldn't get the second log. What's happening is the timer is ticking down even though you're stopped on a breakpoint, and when execution returns to the program, the result of the timer is evaluated before the button release is evaluated.

I'm not exactly sure why things happen in this order - why can't the button release be handled before the timer event? But you can see that **in normal execution without a breakpoint, it's not even a question of what happens first - a short button tap will cause handleButtonReleased to be called  before the timer can go off**.

I suspect that in your case, Apple's keyboard is doing something similar, and you're setting a breakpoint that's holding your touch in stasis while a timer somewhere decides that yes, this is indeed a long press! Even though it really isn't. I don't have a workaround, but hopefully this shines some light on what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and insights, perhaps they will lead to a work around.  I do not think this was happening with xcode 7, so it must be something new they introduced, but I do not have this version to test.  I was really looking to verify that my delegate was setup correctly or if something had changed in swift 3 that I was not aware of.  I guess I will use print statements to the console for now for debugging:(

Comment: Just FYI - on my machine, this happens in both Xcode 7.3.1 as well as Xcode 8.1. I think your delegate is set up correctly and you should continue to use breakpoints to debug, but write your code to ignore backspace events if one is already being handled.